# why I'm getting duplicate values from unique ones

Tags: php, mysql

My table has 356 rows.

Column `date` is like this:

`2018-02-21 13:44:45`

```
select distinct(date) from archive;
```

result is 356 rows - so there is no duplicates

Column `id` has values from 1 to 356;

```
$x = 1;
while ($x<=356){
    $st = $db->query("select date from archive where id = " . $x);
    $a = $st->fetchColumn();
    $a = str_replace('-', '', $a);
    $a = str_replace(' ', '', $a);
    $a = str_replace(':', '', $a);
    $a = substr($a, 2);
    $stb = $db->query("update archive set id = " . $a . " where id = " . $x );
    $x++;
}
```

Error:
Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'...

Why I'm getting duplicate values?

Also, I can't see the source for `4294967295` value because there is no value in `date` column containing this.

Comment: Once you've finishing replacing the characters, you end up with `20180221134445`, which exceeds the maximum value of your column. `4294967295` is the highest number you can store in an unsigned int column - your value is being truncated to this.

Comment: change the type of id column to bigint

Comment: If you're using `select distinct` you can't be sure there are no duplicates...

Comment: @iainn, you probably mean `180221134445` because of `substr` function ad the end.

Comment: @bonaca Right, yes, I missed that one. Either way, it's higher than your column will allow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this just seems wrong

Comment: I changed the type to `BIGINT` and it works.